# My baby moves violently in womb

Tags: vocabulary

My baby moves violently in womb.
My baby moves vigorously in womb.

Do "Violently" and "Vigorously" have the same meaning?
Which one means move strongly?

Comment: Both of them are too intense to describe a baby's movement. You can use phrase -[billy-o](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/billy-o). My baby moves like billy-o inside my womb. Sounds kinda cute as well :)

Comment: I don't think either is too intense- in fact they're quite vivid and descriptive. "Violently" has a negative connotation, you could use that if the baby's movement was bothersome. As an American English speaker, I've never heard the term "billy-o". It sounds British.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to describe baby movement?

Both violently and vigorously mean move strongly. Violently is more descriptive. As @evan said "Violently" has a negative connotation, you could use that if the baby's movement was bothersome.

Personally I would think **violently is the best of the two**. Often expectant mothers will use words such as **frequently or constantly** to describe baby movement. Vigorously seems too medical for a normal description.

### Finishing the Sentence

It should also be noted that **"moves in womb" is not complete**. You need to add a "the", "my", "his", or "her" between "in" and "womb"

> My baby moves violently in my womb.

Description of the baby moving inside yourself.

> My baby moves violently in her womb.

Depending on context, you could be talking about a pregnant woman or speaking from the perspective of a female baby.

> My baby moves violently in his womb.

Speaking from the perspective of a male baby.

Comment: An interesting, but possibly confusing, take on womb ownership :) "My baby moves violently in her womb" can also be seen from the perspective of the father, talking about his baby inside the mother's womb. Which is how I read it first, making the version with "his" womb quite... strange :) But that is indeed just my (mis)reading :)

Comment: Heh. "...in *his* womb."